# Variable can't seem to recieve an value on c# when connecting to SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am writing an algorithm to deliver tomorrow that requires an integration of C# with a SQL database for testing.

I managed to do the integration and it connects to the database smoothly, but when I add a value to the database it gives an exception error indicating that one of the variables gives a null value. Through further investigation I realized that one of the variables is not receiving the value it should, so it is giving this exception error, how could I solve it?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// add data function classes
using System.Data;

namespace LoginSystem
{
    public class DBConnect
    {
        string ConectionString = "";  // save connection string
        public MySqlConnection connection = null;
        public string server = "127.0.0.1:3306";// MySQL host / ip of the computer
        public string user = "root";// MySQL user
        public string password = "@Gilberto099";// MySQL password 
        DataSet ds;
        DataTable dt;
        public string Table = "teste1"; // initialize db table
        public string ConnectionType = "";
        string RecordSource = "";

        DataGridView tempdata;

        public DBConnect()
        {

        }

        // function to connect to the database
        public void Connect(string database_name)
        {
            try
            {

                ConectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database_name + ";" + "UID=" + user + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

                connection = new MySqlConnection(ConectionString);
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
            }
        }

        // Function to execute select statements
        public void ExecuteSql(string Sql_command)
        {

            nowquiee(Sql_command);

        }

        // creates connection to MySQL before execution
        public void nowquiee(string sql_comm)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(ConectionString);
                cs.Open();
                MySqlCommand myc = new MySqlCommand(sql_comm, cs);
                myc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cs.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }

        // function to execute delete , insert and update
        public void Execute(string Sql_command)
        {
            RecordSource = Sql_command;
            Table = ConnectionType;
            dt = new DataTable(ConnectionType);
            try
            {
                string command = RecordSource.ToUpper();

                //======================if sql contains select==========================================
                MySqlDataAdapter da2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(RecordSource, connection);

                DataSet tempds = new DataSet();
                da2.Fill(tempds, ConnectionType);
                da2.Fill(tempds);

                //======================================================================================


            }
            catch (Exception err) { MessageBox.Show(err.Message); }
        }

        // function to bring selected results based on column name and row index
        public string Results(int ROW, string COLUMN_NAME)
        {
            try
            {
                return dt.Rows[ROW][COLUMN_NAME].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return "";

            }
        }

        // function to bring selected results based on column index and row index
        public string Results(int ROW, int COLUMN_NAME)
        {
            try
            {
                return dt.Rows[ROW][COLUMN_NAME].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return dt.Rows[ROW][COLUMN_NAME].ToString();

            }
        }
        public string ResultsColumn(string COLUMN_NAME)
        {
            try
            {
                return dt.Columns[COLUMN_NAME].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return "";

            }
        }
        public string ResultsColumni(int COLUMN_NAME)
        {
            try
            {
                return dt.Columns[COLUMN_NAME].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return dt.Columns[COLUMN_NAME].ToString();

            }
        }

        // Execute select statement
        public void ExecuteSelect(string Sql_command)
        {
            RecordSource = Sql_command;
            ConnectionType = Table;

            dt = new DataTable(ConnectionType);
            try
            {
                string command = RecordSource.ToUpper();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(RecordSource, connection);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, ConnectionType);
                da.Fill(dt);
                tempdata = new DataGridView();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }


        }

        // count Number of rows after select
        public int Count()
        {
            return dt.Rows.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is all over the place.. `// function to execute delete , insert and update` then uses dataadapter.Fill - that's a select. Please.. take a look at http://dapper-tutorial.net; it'll make your life easier and you can throw all this away

Comment: *I don't have time to learn another NuGet* - honestly, you say that but when you actually look at what Dapper does for you you'll hopefully realize that you don't actually have time to NOT learn it - there is nothing to learn and it massively relieves you of the mind numbing tedium of your current data access

Comment: *when I add a value to the database* - the root of my confusion is that none of this code seems to add anything to a database; there seems to be no INSERT query nor call to data adapter.Update. I see that nowquiee looks like it would be capable of performing an insert, and it's called by Execute_Sql, but nothing appears to call either of them with an insert..

Comment: Among the many issues I see with this code: a cached connection which you are not disposing, and you are calling `Fill` twice. `ToUpper` on the SQL string is just plain bad. I would say that this code is generally way too convoluted, the helper functions aren't actually doing much anyway.

Comment: I tried dapper and now he refuses to connect to my database, it's giving "Can't reach database, Logon failed 'MicrosoftAccount/(the account)"

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be of string data type? (int COLUMN_NAME)

```
// function to bring selected results based on column index and row index
    public string Results(int ROW, int COLUMN_NAME)
    {
        try
        {
            return dt.Rows[ROW][COLUMN_NAME].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            return dt.Rows[ROW][COLUMN_NAME].ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is I want to check an specific column, but want to check every single Row, not one specific row, this part will find and specific row AND an specific column

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and check the error and attach a image of that. If that is possible. So that we know which method failed.

Comment: Is the ResultColumn Method who failed, he recieves a table value (a name in a string) but Connection String don't recieve anything, but as stated in the Connection method, it should

Comment: Hi, you can do something like this.                                                                                                                                                                                                                  **for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    string myColumn= dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
}**                                                                                                                                                                    And then return the myColumn if it is matching with the input parameter column.